# EASTL and SGI Hashtable implemenation

Tags: c++, hashtable

In both implementations, the containers have store a raw array of `node_type` which is essentially a simple linked list that stores a type `T`.

```
// From SGI
template <class _Val>
struct _Hashtable_node
{
  _Hashtable_node* _M_next;
  _Val _M_val;
};
```

I am implementing my own version for educational reasons and I am wondering why they are are not using `std::list<>` container for the buckets? Why write code that already exists in a `std::list<>`?

One reason for this that I came across may be that the `std::list<>` is doubly linked, so there is wasted space. But what if one uses a single linked list? And why not have the `bucket_type` a template parameter, so that it can be changed?

Comment: It's entirely up to the implementation, isn't it? This way you keep the library components as independent as possible. There's no need for the full `list` interface, so it's a lot leaner to just define the few required list operations in place.

Comment: @KerrekSB: How is it leaner if it takes the same amount of space (assuming a singly linked list or an `std::array` is used)? Isn't it actually going against what we are usually taught about code reuse? The mentioned implementations have re-written parts of the list class which seems in-efficient, especially if, say, the `list<>` is changed to be, let's say, faster and better down the road and `hashtable` does not benefit from it.

Comment: It's leaner in the sense that you end up compiling less code when you use only the hashtable class in a translation unit than if you pulled in a whole other container header. For EASTL, I suppose that it'll also make the allocator use more transparent to the library maintainers.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That makes sense. Reduced coupling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for **not** using a list class [template] for the buckets in these implementation is that they didn't have a singly linked list and `std::list<T>` is doubly linked: the extra cost of the unnecessary back pointer in terms of run-time and size would be considered bad. C++2011 now has `std::forward_list<T>` which pretty much came out of the desire to use it e.g. in a hashed container. This might raise the question: why didn't they add a singly linked list then? The answer to this is also simple: a singly linked list can't follow the standard's container requirements and it was left for later to make the appropriate choices.

Comment: Can you clarify "a singly linked list can't follow the standard's container requirements" what requirements couldn't be met?

Comment: @JaredKrumsie: Just look at the interface of `forward_list` to see the differences, what with all the `before_begin` shenanigans and such like. The usual iterator logic doesn't work on singly-linked lists.

Comment: @JaredKrumsie: the container requirements mandate that e.g. erase(it) erases the element indicated by the iterator from the container. To do this, iterator would effectively need to point to the prior element. However, if this is the way it is set up I could have two iterators to consecutive elements and remove the first: this would invalidate the iterator to an element which is not being removed in a node-based container. Thus, std::forward_list needed to deviate in some form (probably there were more reasons by my brain seems to be fried).

Comment: @DietmarKuhl: That problem is easily remedied by swapping the next node with the node the iterating is pointing to and deleting the next node. There must be other reasons however.

Comment: @Samaursa: this doesn't solve the problem because references and pointers to non-erased objects are meant to stay valid, too. The choices are either sacrificing handy guarantees for node based containers or the interface. Either approach renders generic code depending on the concepts to be wrong. Changing the interface causes a compile-time error rather than a potentially hard to track run-time error and thus the interface was changed.